# Measure on set of complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

What i know is if we want to intigrate some real valued  function then domain should be measurable space.i faced two type of integration on complex analysis.(1) integration of complex valued function of real variable (2) and integration of complex valued ,complex variable function.    My question is in either cases is there any default measure defined on set of complex number? Or it is possible to define integration with out any kind of measure.?

Answer (score 1):

- Since $\mathbb C$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$,measures on $\mathbb C$ can be naturally identified with measures on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In particular, you have a canonical (real, 2 dimensional) Lebesgue measure.
- Expressions written on the form $f(z) dz$, where $f$ is a holomorphic function, can be integrated along paths, without the need for a measure, by the formula $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz=\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$. Here $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ is a piecewise $C^1$ curve.
  The good framework to really understand this definition is the notion of differential forms.

Comment: u said "without the need for a measure".does it mean that without using measure that integration can be done, but there exist measure ,which will do same thing?

Comment: @MEETPATEL just remember that the notation $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ is only a notation. the actual definition of this type of integral is $\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$. this is an integral of a complex-valued function defined on $[0,1]$; the measure is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ (you can also think about it as a Riemann integral)

Comment: thank you ! the word "NOTATION'  cleared my all dought  ! thanks again !